# Using PHP Boolean in JQuery If-statement

Tags: php, jquery, variables, html

I want to use a php boolean variable inside a jquery if-statement. This is my code:

```
if(<?php echo $show_login_error ?>)
    $(".login_error").show();
```

.login_error is a class for a span element. If the $show_login_error variable is true, then I want to show the span, if not then hide it. By default the span is hidden and $show_login_error is false. Unforunately, the span shows regardless of the variable value so I'm guessing my code is wrong. What should I change to make it right? Thanks

Comment: This is simpler if you invert the decision and push a notification to the client with the PHP if block, and not just dispatch a decision to be observed by the client. So put the `if` in the PHP and have it print the `$('.login_error').show()` if `true`.

Comment: so first intialize with `0` and where you have done chnages in order to show it make chnage to 1 and then after have this condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make sure `.login_error` is hidden by default (`display:none`).

Then, try

```
if(<?php echo (int)$show_login_error ?>)
    $(".login_error").show();
```

just to make sure it prints 0 or 1 (because `echo false` doesn't print a single character)

```
echo false;      //prints nothing
echo true;       //prints '1'
echo (int)false; //prints '0'
echo (int)true;  //prints '1'
```

**EDIT**

Other solutions provided below will work too! ;-)

Comment: peeeeerfecct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($show_login_error == true) ?>
$(".login_error").show();
<?php else: ?>
$(".login_error").hide();
<?php endif; ?>
```